# How to get current alexa skill icon from amazon

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am wondering if there is a way to get current alexa skill icon by url. Because I need skill icon url in my apl template.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to extract the skill.json file that contains the information about the skill. You can do this from ASK CLI by typing,

```
$ ask api get-skill -s {skill_id} --stage development > skill.json
```

replace {skill_id} with your skill id which you can get from the skill console online. it will be in smallIconUri and largeIconUri.

Hope that helps.

Comment: ok, but is there option to access this skill icon by url address with skill id?